# kubectl: describe annotations for persistent volume claims

Tags: kubectl

New to `kubectl`.  I have been tasked with generating a report (via bash script) that retrieves specific annotations from persistent volume claims (PVC), and I am having trouble.

From what I am told, there is at least 1 annotation that describes if a PVC is backed up by Velero or not.  This annotation is stored within the PVC.

The psudeo-code goes like this:

```
Foreach Cluster in ClusterList
    Obtain its kubeconfig file
    Foreach Namespace in AllNamespaces
        Print out Cluster, Namespace, PVC name, Annotation (containing search term)
```

I can easily loop through each cluster and obtain its kubeconfig file.
I use `kubectl describe namespaces` to get that list inside each cluster.

As I loop through the persistent volume claims, there are 13 key-value pairs in the output of
`kubectl describe persistentvolumeclaims`.  I am only interested in 2 key-values: *Name* and *Annotations*.  Within those Annotations, I am looking to see if the word "velero" is present.

I have tried to apply other commands and flags with little success:

- Seems the `-o` format flag does not apply to `kubectl describe`
- `kubectl annotate persistentvolumeclaims --list` returns **error: resource(s) were provided, but no name, label selector, or --all flag specified**, but the `--help` does not describe how to pass a name to `kubectl annotate`.
- `kubectl get persistentvolumeclaims` does not list annotations.

What other methods are there?

I am fine if the output says that there are no PVCs present.  It is actually good information to report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chasing a red herring with the `describe` sub-command it seems.  The annotation output is hidden metadata that is accessible via `kubectl get` using the `-o` flag.  For example:

`kubectl get persistentvolumeclaims -o json`

and can be further parsed by piping the output to `jq`